# Search JSON data in ember.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, ember.js

I am using ember.js for my project where we are fetching mysql data as JSON into the application.

```
   App.ContactsRoute=Ember.Route.extend({
        model:function(){
            return $.getJSON('../getJSON.php?db=db1&table=contact_info',function(contacts){
            console.log(contacts);
            return contacts;
        });
    }
});
```

And in the index.html file inside the contacts template

```
<tbody>

    {{#each contacts in model}}
    <tr>
      <td>

      {{contacts.contactdata.contact_name}}

      </td>
      <td><a href="#" {{action 'deletecontact' contacts}}><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" style="color:red;"></i> </a>
</td>
      </tr>
        {{/each}}

    </tbody>
```

I want to create a search box where user types the name of the contact and the name is shown from the list

Please guide me as I am new to Ember.JS

Comment: Are you looking for something like typeaheadjs?

Comment: @Oliver : Yes, but the result should not be a drop-down. The model should be sorted as a person types

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fikuk/4/edit

Comment: Thanks @blessenm I think i got the idea. But it used Fixture Adapter.

Comment: FixtureAdapter is just a data source. You filtering code shouldnt care where the data comes from. Just filter the controller's model irrespective of the data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this question myself.

I tried using a REST API , which I was not using earlier.
The API is built upon Restler framework for PHP.

Using this API , my problem was solved

Thanks all